# How to replicate a slice of a vector k times into another vector?

Tags: vector, rust

I have a vector `a` and I need to replicate a slice of this vector, say `a[n..n+3]`, `k` times.

For example:

```
a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 2
k = 3
```

then I would like to generate:

```
b = vec![2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

With some previous help I eventually arrived at the following:

```
a[n..n+3].iter().cloned().cycle().take(3 * k).collect()
```

Would this be Rust-idiomatic? Is there a more preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after reading this [Which is more idiomatic? Functional, imperative or a mix?](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/which-is-more-idiomatic-functional-imperative-or-a-mix/11278)
and running benchmarks below

```
    #![feature(test)]
    extern crate test;

    use test::Bencher;

    #[bench]
    fn bench_target_func(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        let n = 2;
        let k = 3;
        b.iter( || {
            let b: Vec = a[n..n+3].iter().cloned().cycle().take(3 * k).collect();
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_target_imper(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        let n = 2;
        let k = 3;
        b.iter( || {
            let mut b: Vec = Vec::with_capacity(k * 3);
            let mut it = a[n..n+3].iter().cloned().cycle();
            for _ in 0..k*3 {
                b.push(it.next().unwrap());
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_target_imper2(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        let n = 2;
        let k = 3;

        b.iter(|| {
            let mut b = Vec::with_capacity(3 * k);
            for _ in 0..k {
                b.extend_from_slice(&a[n..n + 3]);
            }
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_target_func2(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        let n = 2;
        let k = 3;

        b.iter(|| {
            let b : Vec = (0..k).flat_map(|_| a[n..n+3].iter().cloned()).collect();
        });
    }

    fn main() {
        println!("Hello, world!");
    }
```

I got the following results:

```
    test bench_target_func   ... bench:          31 ns/iter (+/- 0)
    test bench_target_func2  ... bench:          97 ns/iter (+/- 1)
    test bench_target_imper  ... bench:          37 ns/iter (+/- 0)
    test bench_target_imper2 ... bench:          29 ns/iter (+/- 0)
```

It appears that flat_map is much slower.

Comment: So, would this be idiomatic Rust?

Comment: Thanks for the work. It would seem the functional version is both very readable and quite fast. It'd rather take the few ns impact and have clean code.

Comment: `bench_target_imper` does 3 times less work. `for _ in 0..k` should be `for _ in 0..k*3`

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected the code and the results

Answer (score 0):

To me your example seems to be Rust-idiomatic enough, but I would do this:

```
let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let n = 2;
let k = 3;

let b : Vec<_> = (0..k).flat_map(|_| a[n..n+3].iter().cloned()).collect();
println!("{:?}", b);
```

I also propose the following verbose approach, which might be useful in some cases.

```
let a = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let n = 2;
let k = 3;

let mut b = Vec::with_capacity(3 * k);
for _ in 0..k {
    b.extend_from_slice(&a[n..n+3]);
}
println!("{:?}", b);
```